# Validation Rule If a checkbox is checked then another field should not be equal to some value

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule

I have two fields.

1. Closed (c2g__Closed__c) --> Checkbox
2. Status (pse__Status__c) --> Picklist

So if checkbox is checked, then the status should not be equal to Rejected.  Here is what I wrote but it is giving error.

`AND(Period__r.c2g__Closed__c = TRUE)
OR(pse__Status__c <> "Rejected")`

Comment: The syntax you're using for the AND and OR statements is likely why you're getting an error.  Remember, the AND statement syntax looks like this:

AND(logical1,logical2,...)

and the OR statement syntax looks like this:

OR(logical1,logical2,...)

So your equation is not completing the validation the way you are intending.  The below posted formula is appropriate, assessing if the first and second logical expressions are true, and if so, throw an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your validation rule, which is if Period__r.c2g__Closed__c is TRUE and pse__Status__c is "Rejected" you would like an error to appear, I believe this is the validation rule you would create for that:

```
AND(Period__r.c2g_Closed__c = TRUE, ISPICKVAL(pse_Status___c, "Rejected"))
```

If you post the error message exactly, I can give more targeted help.

This code was not compiled or tested, however should give you the gist of what you are looking for.

Comment: yes this is what I want. So `true` is right or I should do `==` ?

Comment: [Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_formulas_cheatsheet.pdf) From cheat cheat and from some quick testing it looks as though either using a single equal sign or a double equal sign will work.

`Period__r.c2g_Closed__c = TRUE` 
will run the same way as
`Period__r.c2g_Closed__c == TRUE`

Comment: Which is the same as `Period__r.c2g__Closed__c`. Checkboxes automatically count as a Boolean value.